# Error 2026 windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

When I have uploaded my app for windows phone it come up with the error:

"2026: The file Audio\Unit 4\10. Octubre â€“ October.wav has an incorrect name. File names can only contain ASCII characters."

'Audio\Unit 4\ 10. October.wav' no longer exists and isn't in my code anywhere and it works fine on the emulator does anyone know what is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. do you think it could be because `â` and `€` aren't ASCII characters? That's pretty much exactly what the error message tells you.

Am I misunderstanding, or does that answer your question?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: the audio doesn't exist anymore and it isn't in my code so I don't know what it could be

Answer (score 0):

Set the **Solution Configurations** besides **Target Device Type** to **Release** mode and Build the solution again. Then use the xap file generated in `Bin/Release/` folder to submit on store. Also do double-check if this sound file is getting copied in the `Bin/Release` folder.